# php codes comparison with classic asp

Tags: php, asp-classic

Does anyone knows where to find a site that has a code comparison of php and classic asp? some sort of cheat sheet comparison guide. I need to convert a php site to classic asp.

please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Classic ASP? Is that not long deprecated?

Comment: Cheatsheet for ASP/VBScript: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/asp-vbscript-cheat-sheet/ and one for PHP: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/php-cheat-sheet/. You'll probably find more resources on how to go from Classic ASP to PHP than the other way around.

Comment: Classic ASP is not deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP is a framework so there is no direct comparison to PHP which is a language.  ASP does support vbscript and javascript languages.

Here is a comparison to vbscript/javascript/PHP languages

http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/node/view/30

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

http://www.me-u.com/php-asp/conversionnotes.htm

It obviously has some limitations, but I hope it helps.

Cheers!